# looping from size of list but some index not called when in goroutine

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

i have a dispatcher worker and I loop for the number of jobs from the length of the list , but there are some index not called while looping

```
    var members = []Member{
        {ID: 1, Is: true},
        {ID: 2, Is: false},
        {ID: 3, Is: true},
    }

    numOfWorker := 2
    var durationDelay time.Duration = 5000

    do, _ := worker.NewDispatcher(numOfWorker)
    ch := make(chan worker.MainJob, len(members))

    go func(jobs int) {
        for i := 0; i < jobs; i++ {
            newJob := &worker.NewJob{
                Final: ch,
                Do: func() worker.MainJob {
                    return worker.MainJob{ID: i , Message: "test"}
                },
            }
            do.Dispatch(newJob, durationDelay)
        }
        do.Await()
        close(ch)
    }(len(members))

    for v := range ch {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
```

when i print the `ch`
i got this:

```
{1 test}
{3 test}
{3 test}
```

so the index of 0 and 2 not called, and where is the index 3 from? the length of members is 3, so it gonna called `0 1 2`
do I make mistake here?

the `Do` in newJob is sent the result of worker.MainJob to `Final`

it something like this

```
Final <- Do()
```

the final is `chan worker.MainJob` and `Do` is a function which returns `worker.MainJob`

Comment: [FAQ: Closures and goroutines](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to shadow the loop variable.

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-reference-to-loop-iterator-variable

```golang
        for i := 0; i < jobs; i++ {
            i := i
            newJob := &worker.NewJob{
                Final: ch,
                Do: func() worker.MainJob {
                    return worker.MainJob{ID: i , Message: "test"}
                },
            }
            do.Dispatch(newJob, durationDelay)
        }
```

Comment: would it still gonna be concurrently also if I shadow it ??

Comment: Do you mean "will it still be concurrent"?

Comment: There's no reason why it would change anything like that.

Comment: sorry, what does it mean? i just want to know if i shadow like what u answer, is that gonna be concurrent ?